# Error al upgradear laravel 5.3 a 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, router

Al upgradear a laravel 5.4 me surgio el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene alguna idea? No puedo ni acceder a la ruta principal. Segui todos los pasos del upgrade pero ni idea porque ocurre esto, estoy upgradeando desde la version 5.1, 5.2, 5.3 y ahora la version 5.4, pero de este error no consigo mucho información.

Comment: no le agregues "resuelto" al título de tu pregunta, ya publicaste tu solución basta con que la aceptes y ya

Answer (score 1):

Ya logre solventarlo, al parecer era tenia que limpiar las rutas:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Ademas de ir dejando los archivos base como Kernel,php, app.php y demas como va indicando la actualización requerida.
**Sugerencia para los que actualicen**